# Apache HttpClient PostMan

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, postman, multipartform-data

When using the apache.HttpClient to send a multipart, I generate the following output as below:

18:29:58.800 DEBUG n.n.n.w.e.ServiceImpl -

```
--bEDi1DhmFcmCTebUvLowWpRtw-OscIydQ24RSB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

ChecknLoadEnvironmentData
--bEDi1DhmFcmCTebUvLowWpRtw-OscIydQ24RSB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Dataset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ImportProgramVersion>3.1</ImportProgramVersion> 
    <Year>2012</Year> 
    ....
    .... 
</Dataset>
--bEDi1DhmFcmCTebUvLowWpRtw-OscIydQ24RSB--
```

But this seems to fail with a 500 internal server error
and it succeeds with PostMan.

```
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

ChecknLoadEnvironmentData
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

myXML.xml
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myXML.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

So my question is, can I remove the charset and content-transfer-encoding in java with 
"apache.httpclient"? So I can eliminate the differences between the two requests.
I looked into the library source and does not seem to be possible, it will always default to some value.

(Why does Postman not display my sending xml file?)

Comment: generally it is always a good idea to mention the version of the library that you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the so called 'lax' mode when generating multipart mime entities with Apache HttpClient

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html#setLaxMode()

Comment: This URL is removed can some one update this answer , this is no longer valid.